# Insert password with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to list all of my bitwarden items in a batch file. The cli command is `bw list items` but after this the command line asks me about the master password: `? Master password: [hidden]`

So my question is, how do i write the password in a batch file, so that i don't have to rewrite my password over and over again.

And before someone mentions the security issues, i will not put the password in plain text in the batch file.

My batch file:

```
@echo off
bw list items
```

But as already mentioned after executing this batch file, the command line asks me after the master password, and i want a batch command that writes the password for me, so that only the output will be shown in the console.

Comment: Has `bw` got a command-line parameter where you could input your password?

Comment: How do you think the password will not be in plain text in the batch file if you want it in the batch file?

Comment: No, bw does not have a command-line parameter, but i can use the session key that bitwarden sends me after the login, so that i don't have to write my password over and over again.

Nevertheless, thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you keep the plain text session key from being intercepted, or more specifically, others from being able to interact with your now, less protected BitWarden database, whilst this script remains active. I just need to understand the process you are using. On this site, in order for us to assist you with your specific issue, we need to be able to reproduce it, currently we cannot do that, unless you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65926362/edit), and provide more information.